# SSL with Apache and Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https, amazon-ec2, apache2, passenger

I tried to add SSL support to my server with configuration from http://www.napcsweb.com/blog/2012/07/24/securing-a-rails-app-on-passenger-with-ssl/

```
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#  ServerName 54.215.6.127
#  RewriteEngine On
#  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
#</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
#<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName 54.215.6.127
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/my_app/current/public
  <Directory /home/ubuntu/my_app/current/public>
     Satisfy Any
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     Require all granted
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>

  #SSLEngine on 
  #SSLOptions +StrictRequire 
  #SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/54.215.6.127.crt 
  #SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/54.215.6.127.key 
</VirtualHost>
```

See that I commented line to set server to previous state, i.e. non SSL, but now server is unresponsive.

I do have keys as suggested in napcsweb blog: key, csr, and crt.

1. What am I missing in SSL configuration?
2. Passenger just stopped working, how could I start it again?

## Update

It worked but just with http after change configuration, I commented:

```
     #Satisfy Any
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     #AllowOverride all
     #Require all granted
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
```

And restarted server

```
sudo apachectl restart
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But anyway, I need to set https.

## Update 2

Ports 80 and 443 are listening, but for some reason 443 does not respond.

Comment: You can tell if the passenger module is being loaded by running `$ /usr/sbin/httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES` from the command line (httpd may be in another location on your machine)

Comment: `-bash: /usr/sbin/httpd: No such file or directory`. And `which httpd`  returns nothing.

Comment: I assume you are using ubuntu from your question.  Try `apachectl` with the same arguments

Comment: ` passenger_module (shared)` also `  ssl_module (shared)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an error in my EC2 security group. I allowed access to port 443 and it worked.